# Android - change image of ImageButton when pressed and release

Tags: android, button, onclick, pressed

I would like to set image1 for the button, but when it is pressed - change it to image2. After releasing, the button should be again an image1. I tried to do it this way in onClick() method:

```
  button.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
       if(button.isPressed())
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
```

but after first pressing the image of button changed to the image2 and stayed like that.
Could You help me with that problem?

Answer (score 2):

I think this is what you want:

```
MyCustomTouchListener myCustomTouchListener = new MyCustomTouchListener();
button.setOnTouchListener(myCustomTouchListener);
```

Now the MyCustomTouchListener :

```
class MyCustomTouchListener implement OnTouchListener {
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
    {
        switch(event.getAction()){
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            // touch down code
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
            break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            // touch move code
            break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            // touch up code
            button.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this easily with a [state list drawable](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList), and it requires no additional java code on your part (unless you are creating a `StateListDrawable` at runtime, but even that is a more suitable approach than implementing custom touch interaction).

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
int dispImg = 0;
button.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
if (button.isPress()) {
    if (dispImg == 0) {
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.image2);
        dispImg = 1;
    }
    else if (dispImg == 1) {
        button.setImageResource(R.drawable.image1);
        dispImg = 0;
    }
}
```

Explanation: dispImg keeps track of the image you're showing. When it is 0, it means that the 1st Image is showing and so, we should switch to the 2nd.

Hope I Helped :D